# Identity property of AuthenticationTicket class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication, owin-security

Identity property of AuthenticationTicket class doesn’t contain the UPN claim for external users. Is this an expected behaviour? Any one issues with this previously? `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt152195(v%3Dvs.113)` UPN claim exists for the internal users though!

Comment: Hi s-a-n. Do you mean a social user who has logged in through Azure AD B2C?

Comment: Yes Chris...anyone who is not part of that azure ad domain but added as external users to the azure ad